# How to force id to increase automatically

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
     id INTEGER,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here id does not necessearily auto-increment. So how can I force it to do so?

Using SQL Lite

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using sqlite.

Comment: Oh, you should probably mention that in your post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
);
```

on sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you will want to use AUTO_INCREMENT, like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
     id INT auto_increment,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

If you are using Microsoft SQL, use IDENTITY, like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
     id INT IDENTITY,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Edit: since you're using SQL Lite, take a look at this: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Actually `id INT IDENTITY` is the syntax in MS SQL Server, I think INT works in MySQL as well.

Comment: Ahh good catch, just changed it.  I just copied/pasted his and added identity

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL-Server use [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
     id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b876d/1/0)